# JSONArray not displaying in recyclerview

Tags: php, android, json, android-recyclerview

I am getting error :

> org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of...

I already checked my JSON using postman, and it is listing correctly.

I also tried putting static values in recyclerview and it is displaying correctly.

this is my activity which has recyclerview: (note that I am using fragment)

```
public class DormFragment extends Fragment {

    private static String URL_PRO = "http://192.168.100.7/tforandroid/v1/newjson.php";



    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    private List<User> userItems;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dorm, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        userItems = new ArrayList<>();


        //BELOW IS JUST THE STATIC VALUES THAT ARE DISPLAYING CORRECTLY TO CHECK IF RECYCLERVIEW IS WORKING. 
        /*
        for(int i = 0; i<=10; i++) {
            User userItem = new User(
                    "0" + (i+1),
                    "Ross Lawrence",
                    "RenzLawrence",
                    "Ross@email",
                    "password123"

            );
            userItems.add(userItem);
        }

        adapter = new MyAdapter(userItems, getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        */


        loadRecyclerViewData();


        return v;
    }

    private void loadRecyclerViewData() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRO,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("loginprofile");


                            for(int i = 0; i< array.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                User u = new User(
                                        o.getString("id"),
                                        o.getString("name"),
                                        o.getString("username"),
                                        o.getString("email"),
                                        o.getString("password"));
                                userItems.add(u);

                            }

                            adapter = new MyAdapter(userItems, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error "+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }
                },


                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

my PHP:

```
<?php

#CHECK IF REQUEST METHOD IS POST
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    #INCLUDE DATABASE CONNECTION FILE
    include("connection.php");

    #CREATE CONNECTION
    $connection = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPassword, $DatabaseName);
    if ($connection -> connect_error){
        die("Connection Failed: " . $connection -> connect_error);
    }


    #FILTER DATABASE WITH USERNAME AND PASSWORD FROM THE POST REQUEST
    $sqlmo = "SELECT * FROM tblaccount";

    #EXECUTE QUERY AND COUNT ROW RESULTS
    $sqlresult = $connection -> query($sqlmo);

    try {
        if ($sqlresult -> num_rows > 0) {
            while ($rows[] = $sqlresult -> fetch_assoc()) {
                $arrayLoginResult = array('loginprofile' => $rows);
                $json = json_encode($arrayLoginResult);
            }

            echo $json;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "$e";
    } finally {
        #CLOSE CONNECTION
        mysqli_close($connection);
    }

}

?>
```

I am getting error org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of...
it doesn't display anything

Comment: Well, show us an example of the JSON, please.

Comment: `http://192.168.100.7` are you sure that your phone is able to access this URL?

Comment: Check your "response", the value is incorrect probably isn´t a json object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are not getting any response because of your PHP API allows only POST method and in your StringRequest you are using the GET method.

Answer (score -1):

**The problem is basically that you are not gettin a Json "response"**, the value of `response` is incorrect and probably is not a json object.

```
      @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
               ...
               ...
```

if you are using JSONObject be sure to get  a JSON object with "{" as a container.

---

> If the .json starts with "**{**" and use this character as container it is considered as a Json Object.
>
> If the .json starts with "**[**" and use this character as container it is considered as Json array.

---

> I already checked my JSON using postman, and it is listing correctly.

Probably you can reach the ip from your pc but the mobile device can´t get a response.